# how to resolve access denied while executing mongo.exe in windows 7 ultimate?

Tags: mongodb, windows-7

I downloaded mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.8-rc1-1-g7cc1cf4.zip, unzip it. Getting Access denied not able to resolve. Is there any other way to configure mongodb and install? I opened cmd.exe as administrator. Run the command mongo.exe or mongod.exe, got the error as ACCESS DENIED. I tried with mongod --config D:\Java Software\mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.8-rc1-1-g7cc1cf4\mongo.config getting Access denied. After running mongo.exe screen shot

[image: Access Denied error]
mongo.config file as follows.

```
##store data here
dbpath=D:\Java Software\mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.8-rc1-1-g7cc1cf4\data
##all output go here
logpath=D:\Java Software\mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.8-rc1-1-g7cc1cf4\log\mongo.log
##log read and write operations
diaglog=3
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with mongodb. You need to change the security settings for the files in Windows. See here for guidance: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dI10QI3xEOUJ:windows.microsoft.com/en-id/windows7/how-do-i-open-a-file-if-i-get-an-access-denied-message+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us (cached link because MS removed this from their site)